# LINQ AsNoTracking running slow

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq

I have a need for a non edited list of items from my DB.
It was running slow so I was trying to squeak some speed increases.

So I added AsNoTracking to the LINQ query and it ran slower!

The following code took on average 7.43 seconds. AsNoTracking is **after** the Where

```
var result = await _context.SalesOrderItems.Where(x => x.SalesOrderId == SalesOrderId ).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

The following code took on average 8.62 seconds. AsNoTracking is **before** the Where

```
var result = await _context.SalesOrderItems.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.SalesOrderId == SalesOrderId ).ToListAsync();
```

The following code took on average 6.95 seconds. The is no AsNoTracking

```
var result = await _context.SalesOrderItems.Where(x => x.SalesOrderId == SalesOrderId ).ToListAsync();
```

So am I missing something?  I always though AsNoTracking() should run faster, and is ideal for read only list.
Also this table has two child table.

Comment: The placement of `AsNoTracking` shouldn't matter. Is there any lazy loading involved? Without tracking that could take more time because EF can't reuse previously fetched entities.

Comment: @GertArnold there is two child tables

Comment: read this: https://dotnetcultist.com/maximizing-entity-framework-core-query-performance/

Comment: But do they actually load when `result` is accessed later in the code? Which queries do you see running?

Comment: @AshleyKilgour did You find correct answer for Your question?

Answer (score 0):

> The first time a query is run it must be compiled. If entities are
>   already tracked by the context, then a tracking query will return
>   those instances rather than creating new.

That is the reason why tracked entities might execute faster then with AsNoTracking().

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14366

But execution time about 7 seconds indicates that it is not issue with/no Tracking. It meens issue with data base (not indexed  column for example), About 1.5 bilions records are got with 30 mls but not seconds if data set up properly.

Comment: It isn't just first time it's slow, I ran it six times and worked out the average, the first read wasn't slower.

Comment: Is SalesOrderId  indexed column into SalesOrderItems table ? Also how many records contain in SalesOrderItems table ? And could you provide whole code starts since DataContext creation ?